# Apex SOQL query removing object type designation from id in query

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I am attempting to query a custom object that has a master detail lookup relation with opportunities.  When I build the query dynamically I am getting an SOQL error:

> System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'A000000VmhPyIAJ'

The first three characters of the ID have been dropped in that exception, the full ID is:

> 006A000000VmhPyIAJ

If I dump the query string with System.debug I get this (with the full ID):

> SELECT  id,  isdeleted,  name,  createddate,  createdbyid,  lastmodifieddate,  lastmodifiedbyid,  systemmodstamp,  lastactivitydate,  opportunity__c,  issue__c,  description__c,  ... FROM Exceptions__c WHERE Opportunity__c = 006A000000VmhPyIAJ

If I pass this exact same string into the database.query() I get results as expected.

Anyone have any idea what is causing this?  The code that is generating that query is a library that I use for hundreds of other queries through out our custom Apex, and none of those queries are failing.

The actual query block:

```
try {

    String query = 'SELECT  id,  isdeleted,  name,  createddate,  createdbyid,  lastmodifieddate,  lastmodifiedbyid,  systemmodstamp,  lastactivitydate,  opportunity__c,  issue__c,  description__c,  ... FROM Exceptions__c WHERE Opportunity__c = 006A000000VmhPyIAJ';
    exceptions = database.query( query );
```

} catch(DmlException e) {

```
    System.debug('DmlException: ' + e);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to escape single quotes on the where clause value.

> WHERE Opportunity__c = '006A000000VmhPyIAJ'